# How do I make the matplotlib toolbar able to dock to the side in a pyqt5 window?

Tags: python, matplotlib, pyqt5, qtoolbar

I have embedded a matplotlib figure in a pyqt5 window along with the toolbar, this is my code:

```
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import NavigationToolbar2QT as NavigationToolbar
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg as FigureCanvas
from matplotlib.figure import Figure
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets


class PlotWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(PlotWindow, self).__init__(parent=parent)

        self.figure = Figure(tight_layout=True)
        self.canvas = FigureCanvas(self.figure)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.canvas)

        self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar(self.canvas, self)
        self.addToolBar(self.toolbar)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    mw = PlotWindow()
    ax = mw.figure.add_subplot()
    mw.show()

    exit(app.exec_())
```

And this is what it looks like:

[image]

I can drag the toolbar to the bottom and dock it there:

[image]

But I can't dock it to the side (left or right).

**This is something you can do with any other standard pyqt5 toolbar, why does it not work with the matplotlib toolbar? and how do I make it work?**

I can do it in code by changing this line:

```
# self.addToolBar(self.toolbar)
self.addToolBar(QtCore.Qt.LeftToolBarArea, self.toolbar)
```

The result is:

[image]

Which is what I'm after, but if I then undock the toolbar from the left side I can no longer dock it there again and can only dock it in top and at the bottom.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The QToolBar provided by matplotlib is configured to only allow dragging on the top and information as seen in [the source code](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/main/lib/matplotlib/backends/backend_qt.py#L638-L640):

```py
self.setAllowedAreas(QtCore.Qt.ToolBarArea(
    _to_int(_enum("QtCore.Qt.ToolBarArea").TopToolBarArea) |
    _to_int(_enum("QtCore.Qt.ToolBarArea").BottomToolBarArea)))
```

The solution is to establish all areas:

```py
self.toolbar.setAllowedAreas(QtCore.Qt.ToolBarArea.AllToolBarAreas)
```

Comment: Awesome thanks, that works. However I see now why that might be the case, because when placed at the side it causes a weird resizing issue where the toolbar will grow wider when hovering over the figure. I guess fixing that will have to be the subject of a new question.